# UNUserNotificationCenter alerts only firing when unlocked/app in foreground

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, notificationcenter

I am working on an iOS/Apple Watch app, which includes a timer. When the timer is set, it sets a local alert to fire when the timer completes. It works great when the app is open and in the foreground, but does not alert on the lock screen or if you switch apps.

Same behavior iOS and Watch
The app is requesting `.alert`, `.sound`, and `.badge` permissions, and all are granted.
I have tried firing in `x` seconds vs. at a specified time, same behavior
I saw someone say it needed to run over 60 seconds, that did not change the outcome.

Relevant code:

```
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { success, error in
                if  success {
                    print("Notification Permission Set")
                } else if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = "LE Timer"
            content.subtitle = "Timer Complete"
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
            let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: runFor, repeats: false)
            notificationId = UUID().uuidString
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: notificationId, content: content, trigger: trigger)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: I had a function that was supposed to remove the notification if the timer was stopped, and it was set up wrong, so it removed the notification when the timer was running. I also ended up setting a hardcoded notification ID, which works since there should never be 2 alerts at the same time.